# How to test Fiori app in eclipse using Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have downloaded the fiori app in Eclipse and extended it. Now I need to test this app in Tomcat. My app structure is below.

[image]

Can someone explain it to me how can I test it without uploading it back to Gateway system?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a really tricky task depending on your application architecture.

Here are some things which sould be modified:

- Update of reference to the SAP UI5 bootstrap in index.html may be necessary (you have to deploy the UI5 library to tomcat or you can use an absolute path to a remote UI5 library)
- Backend connection should be enhanced (including URLs). Note if you want to connect to the original source, you can experience some-origin policy issues. If you don't want to use live data, you can setup and use a mock server.

It would be great if you can update your question with error messages or trace information.

You mentioned 'Fiori app'. If it's a real fiori app integrated into Fiori Launchpad, you won't be able to test the application in this framework (you can emulate a static FLP using a mock application descriptor and modified ushell, but to be honest, it isn't worth it). Of course, you can use the original index.html to display the content without FLP framework.